# How is a state of $|0\rangle$ created experimentally?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, quantum-computer, quantum-measurements

In the context of quantum computing, many times in textbooks and online courses, they say "we generate a state of $|0\rangle$", and then proceed to apply quantum (logic) gates.

My question is: how would we practically ensure that a generated state is actually $|0\rangle$, rather than $|1\rangle,\,|+\rangle,\,|-\rangle$, or any other state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|0\rangle$ is typically a ground state, separated from the other (*excited*) states by a gap $\Delta$. One typically lowers  the temperature below the gap, $k_BT\ll\Delta$ and waits for long enough to be sure that the system has relaxed to the ground state.

There have been extensive research in *initialization* of quantum computers in the early 2000, for various systems. The difficulty here is that, in order to perform quantum computation, one typically wants to reduce the decoherence, i.e., one chooses systems with very long lifetimes of the excited states. This means that one needs to wait for a very long time in order to initialize the system in state $|0\rangle$. Alternatively, one may try to control the decoherence (i.e., the coupling to the bath) - making it strong when initializing the system, and switching it off to carry out the computation.